# Error can't execute function from another class for the same object

Tags: c++, oop

```
[path]\CODSE202F-016 CW2.cpp|68|error: 'class User' has no member named 'deposit'; did you mean 'total_deposit'?|
[path]\CODSE202F-016 CW2.cpp|74|error: 'class User' has no member named 'withdraw'; did you mean 'total_withdraw'?|
```

Basically I created a object "a" in user class and I want to execute a function in another class for the same object "a" how do I do that ?

```
// Business Scenario : E-Banking portal with withdrawals,deposit,check balance function,updating pass book etc...
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class User
{   public:
        int ac_no;
        char name[50];
        float balance,deposit_amount,total_deposit,withdraw_amount,total_withdraw;
};

class Account : public User
{   public:
    float deposit(float deposit_amount)
    {   balance=balance+deposit_amount;
        cout<<"Updated balance after deposit : "<<balance<<endl;
    }
    float withdraw(float withdraw_amount)
    {   balance=balance-withdraw_amount;
        cout<<"Updated balance after withdrawal :"<<balance<<endl;
    }
};

class PassBook
{
};

int main()
{   User a;
    int menu;
    int c;
    c=1;
    while (c>0)
    {   cout<<"\tWelcome to the E-Banking portal"<<endl;
        cout<<"  [1] Enter user details"<<endl;
        cout<<"  [2] Display all user details"<<endl;
        cout<<"  [3] Deposits/Withdrawals"<<endl;
        cout<<"  [4] Exit Menu"<<endl;

        cin>>menu;
        if (menu==1)
        {

        }
        else if (menu==2)
        {

        }
        else if (menu==3)
        {   system("cls");
            char menu2;
            float deposits,withdrawals;
            int d;
            while (d>0)
        {
            cout<<" [A] Deposit"<<endl;
            cout<<" [B] Withdraw"<<endl;
            cin>>menu2;

            if (menu2=='A')
            {
                cout<<"Enter Deposit amount : ";
                cin>>deposits;
                a.deposit(deposits);
            }
            else if (menu2=='B')
            {
                cout<<"Enter Withdraw amount : ";
                cin>>withdrawals;
                a.withdraw(withdrawals);
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"Wrong input Try Again";
                continue;
            }
            d++;
        }
        }
        else if (menu==4)
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: User class don't have deposit() or withdraw() method. So,  You can call these method. only Instance of Account class call these methods.

Comment: I'm really sorry if I wasn't clear on my post.
I want to reuse the a object and execute functions from acount class

Comment: You are inheriting "User" class into "Account". So, All you have to do is create a instance of Account class instead of User.

Comment: please explain more about your problem/expectation from the above code snippet to help your question be understandable.

Comment: I have created the object from the wrong class. Doing Account a; instead of User a; fixed it. Thanks –

Comment: It took me a while to find the lines that trigger the errors. A [mre] would make answering easier. This question does not require a menu system. You could have trimmed your main function down to `int main() { User a; a.deposit(1.0f); }`. While this will not give you an e-banking portal, it will reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1):

I have created the object from the wrong class. Doing `Account a;` instead of `User a;` fixed it. Thanks